# How to remove white flashes on Android app (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, splash-screen

I've been searching for a long time for an answer on my question and still can't understand how to get rid of white flashes when you change screens. I have a black-theme app so it's pretty annoying.

I have already tried to wrap my app with a *View* component and set a *backgroundColor* to dark but it didn't help.

I have found several articles where some possible options are described like change something in **RCTRootView** and so on but I can't find where to change it...

Here are several links that I have read:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1402\

https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/358

Also I have found ***react-native-splash-screen*** and want to try it today but firstly I decided to ask you, guys, whether some other ways exist?

***EDIT***

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: you tried this <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item> right? When white screen issue is there most of the time issue is in our theme So please check that first.

Comment: Am I doing it correctly? Please, see ***edit*** in my question

Comment: Also try <item name="android:windowBackground">Your background</item>

Answer (score 1):

The fact is, the white screen is displayed while `react-native` loads Javascript. So you can't fix it with a javascript screen, because it is not loaded yet, and you can't easily fix it with native android code because the white screen is caused by the react native view.

If you just want to change the background color, you can edit (or create) the `res/values/colors.xml` file to include a `background` color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Then you can set `android:windowBackground` inside your `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

If you want to have a more complex loading screen, you really need to use `react-native-splash-screen` with a custom layout (otherwise you need to replicate its behavior in a custom module)

Comment: I'm sorry it is not working, I actually did it myself yesterday for a project and it worked without a problem. I don't have any other solution right now.  Check here: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2358 for reference